# Brackets used in bmatrix for row vector are too large

Tags: matrices

I am having trouble getting my row vector brackets to be a good length. Currently they come out looking like

[image: image of my current rendering of bmatrix row vector]

when I write `\mathbf{A} &= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{v}_1 & \mathbf{v}_2 \end{bmatrix}`, when it should come out looking like

`$$ \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{v}_1 & \mathbf{v}_2 \end{bmatrix} $$`

[image]

I'm new here and don't know why the above line is not rendering, so I have used a picture instead from that line rendered with mathjax.

Here is the preamble that I am using for a thesis-like document:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside,]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing\small} %formats quotes for questions

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase\leftmark} % adds left header
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase\rightmark} % adds right header
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth {\uppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}} % removes "Chapter N" from header

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{}{20pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries}

\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.78, 0.88, 1}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}}
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
\linespread{1.2}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \mathbf{A} &= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{v}_1 & \mathbf{v}_2 \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.83333}` so to counter the effect of `\linespread{1.2}`.

Comment: "I'm new here and don't know why the above line is not rendering," we do not have mathjax  enabled here so an image is the correct form to  show tex output

Comment: Thanks @egreg, that works well.